# Error when starting StaticServer from react-native-static-server: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.staticServer.start')

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I detached my app from Expo, I installed and linked the react-native-static-server module. I added this piece of code in the App.js file, just before the component definition to see how it works:

```
import StaticServer from 'react-native-static-server';
const server = new StaticServer( 8080, { localOnly: false, keepAlive : true } );

server.start( ).then( ( url ) => {
    console.log( "Serving at URL", url );
} );
```

Now I get this error when I call the start() method:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.staticServer.start')
```

The application keeps crashing and restarting. I only tested it on Android so far. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I haven't seen any issues regarding this on github.

The Logcat in Android Studio for my app shows the following:

```
D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
W/unknown:ReactNative: Tried to enqueue runnable on already finished thread: 'native_modules... dropping Runnable.
W/MessageQueue: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {14699d1} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {14699d1} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:545)
        at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:662)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:631)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:601)
        at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:357)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl.runOnQueue(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:61)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the react-native-static-server repository and realized that it has no updates within the last two months. I assumed that it may have worked with a two months old react-native version.

I downgraded the expo sdk to 25, which is based on react-native@0.52. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do `pod install` after you install react-native-static-server.
simply cd ios and then pod install should work fine.